# De Moivres Theorem question and complex numbers

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Question is:

> Find the cube root of $27 (\cos 30° + i \sin 30°)$ that, when represented graphically, lies in the second quadrant.

I did this:

$27(\cos30°+i\sin30°)^\frac{1}{3}=3(\cos10°+i\sin10°)$

But the answer said to add $360$ to $30$ before dividing by $3$.

> $27(\cos30°+i\sin30°)^\frac{1}{3}$
>
> $=27(\cos390°+i\sin390°)^\frac{1}{3}$
>
> $=3(\cos130°+i\sin130°)$

Why does it say to do this?

Comment: You mean «De Moivre's».

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the answer to $\cos (x/3) + i \sin (x/3)$ to lie in the 2nd quadrant, 
then $x/3$ will have to be between 90 and 180 degrees; thus $x$ is between 270 and 540 degrees.

30 degrees does not satisfy that; but an equivalent angle is 390 degrees or 750 degrees and so forth.  Of these, $390/3 = 130$ lies in the second quadrant so you have to use that representation of the original quantity.

Another way to do this is to note that if $z^3 = x$, then also $(z\omega)^3 = x$, where $\omega$ is any of the three cube roots of $1$.  The non-obvious cube roots are at radius one and angle 120 or 240 degrees.  So whatever answer you got, you were free to add 120 or 240 degrees to the argument.  Your 10 degree can thus be put into the second quadrant by adding 120 degrees.

Comment: +1 for the "other way" approach, essentially no calculation necessary. The whole thing, really, but the geometric approach is just so much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

For positive real $r$ and real $t$, the  3 complex cube roots of $r(\cos t+i\sin t)$ are $$r^{1/3}\cdot[\;cos ((2\pi k+t)/3) +i \sin ((2\pi k+t)/3)\;]\; \text { for } k\in \{0,1,2\}.$$ Which can be confirmed by using DeMoivre's theorem to cube each of these. In your Q, with $t=30^o=\pi/6,$ we want $\pi/2<(2 \pi k +\pi/6)/3<\pi$, which requires $k=1$, and $$(2 \pi k+t)/3= (2\pi + t)/3=(360^o+30^o)/3=130^o.$$